# Unable to access a http service from private IP address over VPC Connector in Google cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-networking, google-vpc

I have a service that runs in a compute instance and can access with private IP address like this(https://172.31.93.233/proxy.php). I want to make an https request from a cloud function to access this service so I created a connector(with IP range: 172.31.0.0/28) to VPC which has an IP range:172.30.0.0/16 and connector have Ingress settings( Allow all traffic) and Egress settings( Route all traffic through the VPC connector). BUT somehow my function failed to complete the request and stated this in a log: "Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: ‘timeout’
Both the VPC and function are in the same region(us-central1)

Extra additional information:
Actually the main https service is deployed at the AWS side and I am using Site to Site VPN b/w AWS to GCP to accessing this service with GCP. I can confirm that this service is accessible at GCP compute instance under the same VPC which I connected to the VPN.

I have created a serverless connector through a web console while creating a function. In IAM I can see the following permission with service accounts:

**1:** Serverless VPC Access Service Agent(Serverless VPC Access Admin, Serverless VPC Access Service Agent)

**2:** Google Cloud Functions Service Agent( Cloud Functions Service Agent, Serverless VPC Access Admin)

**3:** My own account from where I a testing function from GCP(Editor, Owner, Serverless VPC Access Admin)

There are other service accounts as well but I don't think they are related or interesting to testing function etc.

Here is my sample function code:

```
var http = require('https');
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  http
        .get('https://172.31.93.233/proxy.php?api=catalogos_direcciones', resp => {
            let data = ''
            resp.on('data', chunk => {
                data += chunk
            })
            resp.on('end', () => {
                let peopleData = JSON.parse(data)
                console.log(peopleData);
                res.status(200).json(peopleData);
               
            })
        })
 
};
```

Comment: Have you configured firewall rules to access Compute VM?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean to access compute VM? Do you mean a firewall rule for cloud function to accessing this service?

Comment: I mean ingress firewall rules on your VPC network, so that your service was accessible on the assigned port.

Comment: As i wrote this service is accessible everywhere within a VPC so there is no need to add further firewall rule for that.

Comment: Is 1 minute default timeout actually enough? Have you checked in logs if request actually reaches the VM?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that if I used the public IP address of the service within my cloud function and without adding the connector, it works and the result will be within a second.
So the problem is when I use serverless connector to send the traffic from the cloud function to VPC either using public IP or private IP it fails there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220978/discussion-between-user565-and-emil-gi).

Comment: Can you please confirm me what IP range you selected while creating a serverless connector during your test? 
Should it be the same IP range of which have a VPC? Like if my VPC has a range(172.30.0.0/16), do I need to use 172.30.0.0/28 for the serverless connector?

Comment: Indeed, VPC connector should be within your VPC network, this might be the case.

Comment: My VPC has a range(172.30.0.0/16) and the Serverless Connector which I tried so far are range like 172.30.0.0/28, 172.31.0.0/28, and 172.50.0.0/28. But none of them work. Any hint what range should I use for the serverless connector?

Comment: 172.30.0.0/28 should do.

Comment: hmm tried many times. But no luck.